# RSA signing and verification gives unexpected different output

Tags: rsa, signature, verification

Following https://wizardforcel.gitbooks.io/practical-cryptography-for-developers-book/content/digital-signatures/rsa-sign-verify-examples.html , I was trying to sign and verify a simple message using my self generated public and private key. However, I unexpected get a different value for signature and hashFromSignature. Any help is much appreciated.

```
p = <some valid p>
q = <some valid q>

e = 65537
n = p*q

# compute n
n = p * q

# Compute phi(n)
phi = (p - 1) * (q - 1)

# Compute modular inverse of e
d = getModInverse(e, phi)

# Make sure d is computed correctly
print("d:  " + str(d))
check = (e*d)%phi
print(check)

privateKey = RSA.construct((n, e, d))
publicKey = RSA.construct((n, e))

msg = b'A message for signing'
hash = int.from_bytes(sha512(msg).digest(), byteorder='big')
signature = pow(hash, d, n)
print("Signature:", hex(signature))

msg = b'A message for signing'
hash = int.from_bytes(sha512(msg).digest(), byteorder='big')
hashFromSignature = pow(signature, e, n)
print(hex(hashFromSignature))
print("Signature valid:", hash == hashFromSignature)
```

Comment: Works for me. My guess is that your primes p are q are too small. They should be large enough so that p\*q=n is greater than 2\*\*512.

Comment: Can you explain why it is required for p*q = n > 2 ** 512 if i were to use sha512?

Comment: All operations in RSA are mod n. If the hash is already >= n then it gets reduced to its equivalent mod n. As an alternative you can "pre-reduce" the hash, so right after you compute the hash and turn it into an integer you compute `hash %= n`. Then the recovered hash from the signature should match.